# Duda sobre referencia al instanciar un objeto

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo una duda con respecto a la creación de objetos, voy a poner 3 ejemplos:

1. `List<> nuevaLista = new ArrayList<>();`
2. `ArrayList<> nuevaLista= new ArrayList<>();`
3. `List <> nuevaLista = new LinkedList<>();`

Se que `List` es una *interfaz*, y que cualquier clase que implemente `List` debe implementar sus *métodos abstractos*, pero en este caso, `nuevaLista`, ¿cómo puede ser una variable de tipo `List` si esta no es una clase?

Fuera de esa duda, he leido que en el 1 y 3, `nuevaLista` solo puede implementar métodos de la interfaz `List`, entonces ¿cuál es la diferencia entre instanciarlo como `ArrayList` o `LinkedList` o cualquier clase que implementa `List`?

Agradecido de sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando defines List<> nuevaLista; estás declarando una variable de tipo List<> que puede hacer referencia a objetos de todas las clases que heredan de la interface List<>. Esto se llama polimorfismo.

Por tanto, en tu primer ejemplo nuevaLista puede hacer referencia a instancias de objetos de diferentes clases (todas las que implementan List<>) y en el segundo ejemplo nuevaLista solo puede apuntar a objetos de la clase ArrayList<> (a objetos de sus clases hijas, si las tuviera, también).

Lo que no se puede hacer en Java es instanciar interfaces o clases abstractas, pero si que puedes tener una referencia/variable que tenga como tipo una de ellas. Como he dicho antes, esto permite hacer uso del polimorfismo.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente se puede porque LinkedList implementa List al igual que ArrayList, eso lo puedes revisar en la API de Java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si lo se, pero mi duda era cual es la diferencia entre instanciarlo con ArrayList o LinkedList si igualmente no va a poder ocupar los métodos propios de ArrayList o LinkedList

Comment: Su nombre lo dice, LinkedList es "lista ligada" puedes recorrerla hacia adelante o hacia atrás, y ArrayList es una "lista arreglo" puedes obtener cualquier elemento en cualquier momento.

Comment: ok, pero sigue quedandome duda, lo planteo de otra forma, cuando uno hace _List nuevaLista;_ que significa hasta alli? que cosas adquiere la referencia nuevaLista? y cuando ya la instancia con un ArrayList o LinkedList, que otras caracteristicas adquiere?

Answer (score 0):

***LinkedList*** como bien dijeron implementa de ***List*** al igual que ***ArrayList***, pero a diferencia uno del otro ***LinkedList*** esta implementado con una lista doblemente enlazada, en cambio ***ArrayList*** con un array que duplica dinámicamente su tamaño cuando es necesario más espacio.

- Por ello podemos considerar que LinkedList por ejemplo me permite eliminar o agregar elementos con una complejidad de O(1) mientras que un ArrayList en O(n).
- Pero para la busqueda ArrayList es más eficiente ya que presenta una complejidad de O(1) y LinkedList de O(n).

***Conclusión:*** Son diferentes implementaciones para el mismo fin, por lo cual dependiendo el uso que le quieras dar vas a elegir uno u otra.

Espero que te sea de ayuda!

Saludos! :)

Comment: ok gracias, pero sigue quedandome esta duda, lo planteo de otra forma, cuando uno hace _List nuevaLista;_ que significa hasta alli? que cosas adquiere la referencia nuevaLista? y cuando ya la instancia con un ArrayList o LinkedList, que otras caracteristicas adquiere?

Comment: Cuando instancias List lo único que haces es guardar un espacio de referencia a una variable de esa clase, ahora cuando haces el new ArrayList o LinkedList , el compilador pide la memoria al S.O necesaria para esa variable (Ya sea ArrayList o LinkedList).
Ahora bien pongamos un ejemplo:
List<> nuevaLista = new ArrayList<>();
Yo puedo luego sobreescribir nuevaLista con un LinkedList:
List <> nuevaLista = new LinkedList<>();

Pero no puedo hacer lo mismo si nuevaLista es de la clase ArrayList o LinkedList.